# What is the most appropriate way to reference a sender element in C# forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, sender

I'm making a C# form application in which I have a couple of textboxes and comboboxes with placeholder text. I am trying to make it so that whenever said elements enter focus, they will call a method to erase the placeholder text and change its color.

In my little knowledge, it seemed appropriate to create a method that received the enter focus event's "sender" argument. Something along the lines of...

```
private void txtName_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CoolMethod(sender);
        
    }

public void CoolMethod(object sender)
    {
        sender.Text = "";
    }
```

But that doesn't work. I expected having access to the element's properties much as if I were to simply type *txtName.(something)*. Why does it not? How can I do this instead?

I tried looking up documentation on elements and events but it fried my brain. I'm not even sure *what* I'm looking for here to understand what I need and I figured someone else explaining in more human words could help.
Sorry if it's a silly question, but I really didn't manage to figure it out on my own.

Comment: There is something in your logic that is not well thought. What if your user activate your textbox (you clear it) type something valuable, activate another textbox and then click again on the first textbox? Do you want to clear it again from what the user typed?

Comment: Cast it. A Form's elements' parent class is Control. ((Control)sender).Text = ...

Comment: @Steve It is flawed logic but I made that bit simply to illustrate the issue: passing "sender" to a different method. Still, I appreciate the attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does it not?

Because [Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=netcore-3.1) does not have a `.Text` property.

...but simply cast your "sender" parameter to type [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.text?view=netcore-3.1), which does have a `.Text` property.  Don't forget to change the type of the parameter in `CoolMethod()` as well:

```
private void txtName_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CoolMethod((Control)sender)        
}

public void CoolMethod(Control sender)
{
    sender.Text = "";
}
```

From the comments:

> Thank you! Worked wonders. I would like to ask about the
> (Control)sender bit. I've never seen passing an argument with a
> different, specified type. What do you suggest I look up to learn
> about that? Why can the same sender have different types?

Here's the docs on [Casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions).

**All** classes in .Net derive from Object, which means you can reference all controls with a variable declared of type Object.  This isn't always a two way street, though.

All squares are rectangles, but not all rectangles are squares.

So all TextBoxes, for instance, can be referenced with an Object variable, but not all Objects can be cast to TextBox (it might be something else).

In this case, we can be fairly certain that the "sender" parameter is going to be a Control, since that event is generated by a Control.  It is possible to call `txtName_Enter()` manually, though, and pass in parameters that DO NOT make sense.

To guard against that, you can check to see if the sender parameter [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) of type `Control` before casting.  That would like:

```
private void txtName_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Control) // if we pass this test, it's safe to cast to Control below!
    {
        CoolMethod((Control)sender)
    }       
}
```

Comment: You should probably have other logic or structures in place to know whether or not the placeholder text is still there, or whether that particular control has been visited or not.